# Wierd ArrayList values

Tags: java, arraylist

Intent: The program is intended to recieve an input from the user and compare it against the contents of the ArrayList. If the input is not found, the program the input to the list and gives it a winCount of 1. The list is printed with the number of wins following it. In the end the user with the hightest wincount wins. If there is a tie a user is randomly selected.

The problem: My arrayValues are not properly stored

The Team class has been provided with the methods below :

```
public class Team implements Comparable<Team> {
// _-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_-v-_
// CS 1323: Implement this method
/**
 * This is the method you will fix to allow you to return the contents of
 * this Team item in the nice format: "name: winCount".  The current 
 * implementation will allow the program to compile, but it returns nothing.
 * 
 * For example: "Sooners: 3"
 * 
 * @return the formatted String that can then be output to the console.
 */
public String toString(String team, int wins) {
    String winStatement = team + ": " + wins;
    return winStatement;
}
// _-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_-^-_

// Data fields
private String name;
private int winCount;

Team() {
    name = "Sooners";
    winCount = 1;
}

Team(String inputName) {
    name = inputName;
    winCount = 1;
}

Team(String inputName, int inputWinCount) {
    name = inputName;
    winCount = inputWinCount;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------
// Getters and Setters (aka Accessors and Mutators) ===
/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name
 *            the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the winCount
 */
public int getWinCount() {
    return winCount;
}

/**
 * @param winCount
 *            the winCount to set
 */
public void setWinCount(int winCount) {
    this.winCount = winCount;
}

/**
 * Increments the winCount variable by one for this Team
 */
public void incrementWinCount() {
    winCount++;
}

/**
 * This method allows you to check to see if this Team object has the same
 * name as another Team object.
 * 
 * This method allows you to use the contains method in ArrayList to see
 * if any element in an array list has the same name as a specific Team.
 * 
 * @param o
 *            the other Team being compared to.
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return name.equals(((Team) o).name);
}

/**
 * This method allows you to check to see if this Team object has the same
 * name as another Team object
 * 
 * @param otherTeam
 *            one team
 */
public boolean sameName(Team otherTeam) {
    return name.equals(otherTeam.name);
}
/**
 * This method allows you to check to see if this Team object has the same
 * name as another Team object
 * 
 * @param team1
 *            one team
 * @param team2
 *            the other team
 */
public static boolean sameName(Team team1, Team team2) {
    return team1.name.equals(team2.name);
}

/**
 * This method allows you to sort an ArrayList of Team items using
 * Collections.sort
 * 
 * @param o
 *            the other Team being compared to.
 * @return -1 if this Team item should come first, +1 if this Team item
 *         should come after the other, and 0 if this Team item is
 *         equivalent to the other.
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(Team o) {
    if (this.winCount < o.winCount) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.winCount > o.winCount) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }

}
```

I am new to reference variables and ArrayLists, so I suspect the error has something to do with them. The code is below :

```
  public class Project6_ReeceWitcher
  {
      public static void main(String args[]) 
      {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rando = new Random();
    String name = "hi";
    int cycles = 0;
    int value = 0;
    ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    Team myTeam = new Team();
    Team thisTeam = new Team(name);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Advanced Sportsball Tracker!");

    while (!name.equals("x")) // looping print statement
    { // x loop begins
        System.out.println("Which team just won? (x to exit)");
        name = scnr.next();
            if (!teams.equals(name))
                {
                teams.add(thisTeam);
                myTeam.setWinCount(1);
                }
            else if (teams.equals(name))
            {
                myTeam.incrementWinCount();
            }
        cycles++;
    }// x loop ends

    if (cycles == 1) // prints no data if user immediately exits
    {
        System.out.println("No data input");
    }

    System.out.println("Final Tally: "); //  loop to print teams 
    for (Team team : teams) // FIXME
    {
        System.out.println(team);
    }
```

The program runs and outputs these values

Welcome to the Advanced Sportsball Tracker!

Which team just won? (x to exit)

1
Which team just won? (x to exit)

2
Which team just won? (x to exit)
x
Final Tally: 
Team@75b84c92
Team@75b84c92
Team@75b84c92
The winner is the with win(s)

However the intended output is

Welcome to the Advanced Sportsball Tracker!
Which team just won? (x to exit)
Sooners - these values are user inputs and are not printed
Which team just won? (x to exit)
Sooners - 
Which team just won? (x to exit)
Cowboys  - 
Which team just won? (x to exit)
Bears  - 
Which team just won? (x to exit)
Bears  -
Which team just won? (x to exit)
Cowboys  -
Which team just won? (x to exit)
ThatOtherTeam  -
Which team just won? (x to exit)
x
Final Tally:
ThatOtherTeam: 1
Sooners: 2
Cowboys: 2
Bears: 2
The winner is the Cowboys with 2 win(s)!

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: `teams.equals(name)` will never be true, because you are comparing objects of different classes (`ArrayList` and `String`)

Comment: How should I go about comparing them?

Comment: You don’t.  They are incomparable.  (But you might want to compare the name against the `.getName()` of one or more teams that are contained inside the `ArrayList`.)